# Why 'are getting' at sentence 'I'm sorry to hear that your parents are getting divorced.'?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english, british-english

Book [Destination C1&C2](https://www.macmillanenglish.com/catalogue/courses/skills-grammar-and-vocabulary/destination-grammar-and-vocabulary-series/levels-samples), page 6:

> Write the verb in brackets in the correct form, present simple or
> present continuous, in each gap:
>
> I'm sorry to hear that your parents __________ **(get)** divorced.

> ANSWER KEY:
> 3 are getting

I have seen the answer key. Why 'are getting' at sentence 'I'm sorry to hear that your parents are getting divorced.'?

Can this way of grammar used in also British English and American English?

Comment: *Divorce* is a civil proceeding that takes time, a process. They **are making** the necessary arrangements to end the marriage.

Comment: We don't allow images on this site without the full text typed out as well. I have removed the images and added the text.

Comment: It's an idiomatic usage in BrE and AmE: to get divorced or to get a divorce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written in the present continuous, as it is ***...your parents are getting divorced*** has two possible meanings.

It could mean they are engaged in the fairly long legal process of becoming divorced. The verb here would be equivalent to "They are swimming/walking/shopping etc".

But it could also mean they intend to divorce in the near future, and conjugationally equivalent to "They are going to the shops this afternoon/ getting a new car next month" etc.

Only the context will tell you which of these meanings is the intended one.But if you wanted to make it clear it was the first one you could say "...they are in the process of getting divorced".

Answer (score 1):

"Are getting" because it is a process they are in the middle of. "I'm sorry to hear that your parents get divorced" would imply this is something they do habitually, which is grammatically correct but makes no sense in context. As a contrast "I swim in the sea" and "I am swimming in the sea" are both correct but have different meanings. The first means it is something I sometimes do, the second that I am doing it at the moment.